# Unsigned CRC 32 for Python to match Java's CRC 32?

Tags: java, python, networking, crc32

A Python client communicates with a Java server across an unreliable channel, and they must communicate package corruption via CRC32.

On Java's end, the CRC 32 is unsigned:

```
//where data is a byte[]
crc.update(data, 8, data.length-8);
long chksum = crc.getValue();
```

But on Python's end, the CRC 32 is signed:

```
//where some_segment is a bytearray() of data
crc = zlib.crc32(some_segment)
```

Is there a way to compute the checksum in Python's crc32 to match that of Java's? In other words, make python's crc32 unsigned?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can bitwise the result with `0xffffffff` to get an unsigned value:

```
crc = zlib.crc32(some_segment) & 0xffffffff
```

In Python 3 this is the default, so you only need this on python 2.X, but will work for both versions.

Comment: What is the reasoning behind this? Is it because the 9th bit is used to sign?

Comment: In two's complement the last bit signifies negative (not an extra bit). So this works because python ints are not 32 bits, assume that an int is 64 bits (its much more complicated than that), then bitwise-and anything with 0xffffffff (32 bits) will be 0x00000000xxxxxxxx, so will be positive. -1 in 64 bits is 0xffffffffffffffff, so -1 & 0xffffffff = 0x00000000ffffffff. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

Do `& 0xffffffff` on the crc.